# CleanWebpackPlugin config fail when build

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

I tried to implement a webpack config on a Wordpress theme. I want to add the CleanWebpackPlugin and made a correct install of it.

I read a tutorial and I wrote something like this on my webpack.config.js:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./js/build/*','./css/build/*']),
```

After I made my `npm run build` I received this error:

```
clean-webpack-plugin only accepts an options object.
```

and it redirected me to the GitHub project. I read the documentation but didn't find how to solve my problem.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see that CleanWebpackPlugin **v2** was released 18 days ago, It looks like you are using an old option type.

The new version, claims:

> By default, this plugin will remove all files inside webpack's output.path directory, as well as all unused webpack assets after every successful rebuild.

So, if you need to clean a folder that is not in the `output.path`, you probably should follow: [additional v2 information](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin/issues/106).

They introduced a new option to clean paths that are outside of `output.path`:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
  cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['./js/build/*','./css/build/*']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation: https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#options-and-defaults-optional

You probably need:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({
  cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['./js/build/*','./css/build/*']
}),
```